# Unable to install and use pyinstaller inside of github actions

Tags: python-3.x, github, pip, pyinstaller, github-actions

I am trying to install pyinstaller inside of my github actions workflow.
Using `pip install pyinstaller` was fine on `ubuntu-latest` but on `windows-latest` it was not however. It returns the following log.

```
Requirement already satisfied: future in c:\hostedtoolcache\windows\python\3.9.12\x64\lib\site-packages (from pefile>=2017.8.1->pyinstaller) (0.18.2)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for pefile, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: pywin32-ctypes, altgraph, pyinstaller-hooks-contrib, pefile, pyinstaller
  Running setup.py install for pefile: started
ERROR: Operation cancelled by user
  Running setup.py install for pefile: finished with status 'canceled'
Error: The operation was canceled.
```

```yaml
  build:
    name: Build Executables
    needs: create_release
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.config.os }}
    strategy:
      matrix:
        config:
          - os: ubuntu-latest
          - os: macos-latest
          - os: windows-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Setup Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v3
        with:
          python-version: '3.9.12'
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install -r requirements.txt
          pip install pyinstaller
      - name: Build with pyinstaller for ${{ matrix.config.os }}
        run: pyinstaller game.spec
```

*Direct link to github action file*: https://github.com/daanbreur/SwishandFrick/blob/main/.github/workflows/build.yml

Trying to install the missing dependencies manually doesnt resolve the issue however

```yaml
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools
          pip install -r requirements.txt
          pip install pywin32 pefile pyinstaller
```

*Direct link to github action file*: https://github.com/daanbreur/SwishandFrick/blob/main/.github/workflows/build.yml

`ubuntu-latest` fails to locate the `pywin32` package

```sh
Installing collected packages: PyTMX, pygame, future, pyscroll
Successfully installed PyTMX-3.31 future-0.18.2 pygame-2.1.2 pyscroll-2.29
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

And `windows-latest` crashes entirely

```sh
Run python -m pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools
  pip install -r requirements.txt
  pip install pywin32 pefile pyinstaller
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.9.12\x64\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.9.12\x64\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.9.12\x64\lib\site-packages\pip\__main__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main as _main
  File "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.9.12\x64\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.9.12\x64\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.9.12\x64\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.9.12\x64\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\cmdoptions.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.parser import ConfigOptionParser
  File "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.9.12\x64\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pip._internal.configuration import Configuration, ConfigurationError
  File "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.9.12\x64\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\configuration.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pip._internal.exceptions import (
  File "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.9.12\x64\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\exceptions.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.requests.models import Request, Response
  File "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.9.12\x64\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from .exceptions import RequestsDependencyWarning
  File "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.9.12\x64\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\exceptions.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .compat import JSONDecodeError as CompatJSONDecodeError
  File "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.9.12\x64\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\compat.py", line 11, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import chardet
  File "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.9.12\x64\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\chardet\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from .universaldetector import UniversalDetector
  File "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.9.12\x64\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\chardet\universaldetector.py", line 46, in <module>
    from .latin1prober import Latin1Prober
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 846, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 941, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1040, in get_data
KeyboardInterrupt
```

What am I missing for windows and how can I let ubuntu skip the step for windows dependencies.

Comment: Hi @Daan Breur, please show your own effort and try to come up with a minimal reproducible example. Just pasting everything makes the question very long and its unlikely someone is going to answer it. Here are some hints: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi @rethab, I had already cut out a lot of unnecessary information and included my own attempts but I have condensed it even more. Thanks for you help

Answer (score 3):

Big oops on my part.
Windows didn't fail to install the dependencies, Ubuntu failed to zip the archive and that lead to it erroring.
By default [github-actions](/questions/tagged/github-actions) is configured to automatically cancel all other jobs in the matrix. Setting `fail-fast` inside the `strategy` to `false` stops it from canceling other jobs. See docs: [jobs.<job_id>.strategy.fail-fast](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstrategyfail-fast)

```
diff --git a/.github/workflows/build.yml b/.github/workflows/build.yml
index a00be16..34b9e82 100644
--- a/.github/workflows/build.yml
+++ b/.github/workflows/build.yml
@@ -38,6 +38,7 @@ jobs:
     needs: create_release
     runs-on: ${{ matrix.config.os }}
     strategy:
+      fail-fast: false
       matrix:
         config:
           - os: ubuntu-latest
@@ -49,11 +50,11 @@ jobs:
         uses: actions/setup-python@v3
         with:
           python-version: '3.9.12'
-      - name: Install dependencies
+      - name: Install dependencies for ${{ matrix.config.os }}
         run: |
           python -m pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools
           pip install -r requirements.txt
-          pip install pywin32 pefile pyinstaller
+          pip install pyinstaller
       - name: Build with pyinstaller for ${{ matrix.config.os }}
         run: pyinstaller game.spec
       - name: Archive Release
```